# how to check each elements of string array contains data or not in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

i have created web application and using textbox and it can contains multiple line of data becoz i have set its textmode property is multiline.
   my problem is that i want to check each line contain data or not so i using count variable which count how many line contain data.

```
string[] data;
int cntindex;   
data = txt_invoicenumber.Text.ToString().Split("\n".ToCharArray());
cntindex = data.Length;
for (j = 0; j < cntindex; j++)
{
    if (data[j]!="")  
    {
        inv_count++;            
    }        
}
```

Its not working.
 Please help me.

Comment: I'd recommend using string.IsNullOrEmpty().

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because new line is `\r\n` so there is a `'\r'` also on empty lines.
Change the if statement to:

```
if (data[j].Trim().Length != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You don't need to `ToString()` the `.Text` property as it is already a string.

try this

```
string[] lines = txt_invoicenumber.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
int lineCount = 0;
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        lineCount ++;
        this.ProcessLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lb = new String[] { "\r\n" };    
var lines = txt_invoicenumber.Text.Split(lb, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;
```

This will count empty lines too. If you don't want to count empty lines, use the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` value.

Don't count 100% on "\r\n" if you have little control over your environment though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with.

```
String[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\r', '\n' },
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Int32 validLineCount = lines.Length;
```